# Convert moment to format("H[h] m[m]") using moment but its showing invalid date

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I'm trying to convert hours into `H[h] m[m]` format. However when the hours are exceeding 24 it's showing 'Invalid Date'. How can I convert it to the above format?

```
var totalHours = parseInt(row.work_duration_seconds) + parseInt(row.break_duration_seconds); //Output : 95122
row.totalHours = totalHours > 60 ? secondsTimeSpanToHMS(totalHours) : '0h'; //Output:  {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "26:25:22", _f: "HH:mm:ss", _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, …}
row.totalHours = moment(row.totalHours, 'HH:mm:ss').format("H[h] m[m]"); //Output: Invalid Date
```

Comment: I don't think `moment` is the right tool for this. This can be done by some simple calculations.

Comment: @kemicofaghost  moment has duration's, so maybe that might help. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

Comment: @Sourav, did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Would this  help?

```
var hours = 12.5;
moment.utc(hours*3600*1000).format('HH:mm');
//using utc mode. Ambiguous input is assumed to be UTC. Unambiguous input is adjusted to UTC
```